# function return tuple. sometimes get lists, sometimes get tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I write a function to return multiple lists(at least one). It is looks like below:

```
def get_stock_atrributes_data(stock, attrList):
    dbClient = MongoClient()
    db = dbClient.StockAnnual
    #only query the data we need
    query = {attr: 1 for attr in attrList}
    #exclude id
    query['_id'] = 0
    cursor = db[stock].find({}, query).sort([('date', pymongo.ASCENDING)])
    #tranform cursor to list so it becomes iterative
    l = list(cursor)
    res = []
    for attr in attrList:
        res.append([d[attr] for d in l])
    return tuple(res)
```

In order to do it, I use tuple so I can use

```
list1, list2 = get_stock_atrributes_data()
```

to query multiple attributes lists determined by the `attrList`. When I return multiple lists(more than one), it works quite well. But if I only return one list, the result is a tuple containing one list, for example:

```
list1 = get_stock_atrributes_data()
```

The `list1` is a tuple rather than a list now. I read some explanation about returning tuples. It is said that the elements in tuple will be unpacked and assigned automatically. For returned tuple with more than one elements, it works. But for tuple only containing one element, the result is not unpacked. I was confused by this and hope someone can give me explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example, you should be able to use it to modify your code and get the result you're after.

```
def retTup(x):
    return tuple(x)

a,b = retTup([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

This will give:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

Now, if I do:

```
a = retTup([[1,2,3]])
```

I will get a tuple for **a**:

```
a = ([1,2,3],)
```

So instead I retrieve the list as: (**notice the comma**)

```
a, = retTup([[1,2,3]])
```

And now:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

As desired.

Comment: Good answer, but please emphasize the comma.

Comment: Hi, it solved the problem! Could you help me to explain why a simple comma solve the problem?

Comment: The function always returns a tuple, so if you're actually interested in the elements of a tuple you have to access them directly. When you use the comma it accesses the first (and only) element of the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Will the method return only 1 element or 2 elements?  Or is it possible for the method to return X many elements?

You could try setting the result to a variable and then creating a new list of lists:

```
results = get_stock_attributes_data()
arranged_results = []
arranged_results = [arranged_results + element for element in results]
```

The + operator in this case performs the append operation, but since `append()` does not have a return value, it cannot be used here.

This should work with the case in which you are returned a tuple of the form `(X,)` or the form `(X,Y,...)`.